# What tecnologies justin.tv use to stream live videos?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, real-time, live-streaming

What tecnologies justin.tv use to stream live videos ?

thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby on Rails is the application platform, with Flash as the video playback mechanism. Video serving is powered by Python Media Server on a large server farm. Chat runs on Twisted.

Answer (score 1):

Justin.TV uses Adobe Flash.